# If a same variable $t$ is added to all entries of a matrix $A$, express $\det(A)$ as a certain first degree polynomial in $t$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Prove that if the same number **t** is added to each element of the matrix, then the determinant of the new matrix is equal to the determinant of the original matrix plus **t**, multiplied by the *sum of cofactors* of all elements of the original matrix.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Leo to proove it

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: I have taken the liberty to turn your previous title into a more specific one. Do you agree ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notations : Let $\mathbf{1}$ be the column vector of ones and $\text{com}(M)$ the matrix of cofactors of $M$ (also called "co-matrix"). Let $\Omega= \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{1}$ be the matrix with all its entries equal to one. Let $s$ be the sum of all cofactors of a matrix $A$.

We have to prove that

> $$\det(A+t\Omega)=\det(A)+ts \tag{*}$$

Here are 2 proofs :

**First proof :**

Let us recall Cramer's formula :

$$A^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{\det(A)}(\text{com}(A))^T \ \ \text{written under the form} \ \ \ \text{com}(A)=\det(A).(A^{-1})^T\tag{1}$$

Besides, it is easy to establish that the sum of all entries of a matrix $M$ can be written

$$\mathbf{1}^TM\mathbf{1} \tag{2}$$

Consequently, combining (1) and (2),

$$s:=\det(A)\mathbf{1}^T(A^{-1})^T\mathbf{1}\tag{3}$$

The identity we are going to establish is a consequence of the [matrix-determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) under the form :

$$\det(I+uv^T)=1+u^Tv\tag{4}$$

(where $u$ and $v$ are column vectors).

Let us take $v:=\mathbf{1}$ and  $u:=tA^{-1}\mathbf{1}$. (1) becomes :

$$\det(I+tA^{-1}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T)=1+t \ \mathbf{1}^T(A^{-1})^T\mathbf{1}$$

Multiplying LHS and RHS by $\det(A)$, one gets :

$$\det(A(I+tA^{-1}\Omega))=\det(A)+t \ \det(A)\mathbf{1}^T(A^{-1})^T\mathbf{1}$$

(denoting by  $\Omega$ the matrix whose all entries are equal to $1$).

Using (2), we have established (*)

**Final remarks :**

1) matrix-determinant lemma is sometimes called Sylvester's determinant equation, see for example (https://mathoverflow.net/q/186672).

2) We have assumed $A$ invertible. It isn't compulsory, as will be seen in the second proof.

---

**Second proof :**

Let us take, for the sake of simplicity the case of a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

We can write, by calling $A_k$ the $k$th column of $A$ :

$\det (A + t\Omega) = \det[A_1+t\mathbf{1},A_2+t\mathbf{1},A_3+t\mathbf{1}] $

$=\underbrace{\det[A_1,A_2,A_3]}_{\det(A)}  +t \underbrace{(\det[\mathbf{1},A_2,A_3]+\det[A_1,\mathbf{1},A_3]+
\det[A_1,A_2,\mathbf{1}])}_{s'} \tag{5}
$

by multilinearity of $\det$ function ; all other terms having at least two $t\mathbf{1}$, like $\det[t\mathbf{1},A_2,t\mathbf{1}]$ are zero because a determinant with two identical columns is zero.

Besides, it is not difficult to see that $s'=s$ because, by (Laplace) expansion of the different determinants with respect to their "$\mathbf{1}$" columns, we get, by groups of three, all the cofactors of $A$.

Comment: I have provided a second (simpler) proof.